# Files with write permission for all in /proc directory on CentOS 6.4

Tags: permissions, linux-distributions, centos-6

While searching for files writable by others, I'm coming across many files available in subdirectories of `/proc`. I'm not much aware of the usage of these files, but curious to know whether if someone from the machine used "`rm -rf /proc`" or someone writes them for the purpose of corrupting them, then how it is going to harm the server? I'm running CentOS 6.4.

I have the same situation for the `/selinux` directory, here as well I have few files which are writable by others.

Comment: `/proc` is not your regular filesystem. It's a _virtual_ filesystem. It shows you the contents of your memory (RAM) with things like open file descriptors of running processes (among many others). As for why some of its files would be world-writable, beats me. Read more [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/proc-fs.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `/proc` file-system can be used to configure the kernel from within user space by writing data to appropriate files.
[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-proc/index.html)'s some relevant reading.